# Yii - showing treeview with more than two levels in dropdownlist

Tags: php, database, yii, relationship

I have a database table with this structure

```
id title parent_id is_parent
```

parent_id is the id of the parent and I added is_parent as boolean to show the elements that are parents.

I want to extract a treeview out of this database and show it in a dropdownlist. Here is what I'm looking for:

```
level1
   level2
      child1
      child2
   level2_2
      child1
      child2
level1_2
  ...
```

For now I can do this if there are only two levels (parent and child), like this, in my model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
                'getparent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Region', 'parent_id'),
                'childs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Region', 'parent_id', 'order' => 'title ASC'),
    );
}
```

and in the view:

```
 <?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model,'region',CHtml::listData(Region::model()->findAll('is_parent=0'),'id', 'title','getparent.title'),array('prompt'=>'Choose')); ?>
```

I don't know how to change the relationship in the model or change the listData structure two get the results I want.

Answer (score 2):

Optgroup (in dropdown list) can't be nested, so you must to abandon groups.
Just create your own $model::getList() function.

I think you shouldn't use 'is_parent', 'parent_id' is enough. getList() looks like this:

```
public static function getList($id=0) {
    $list = array();
    $models = Region::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('parent_id'=>$id));
    foreach ($models as $model) {
        $childList = Region::getList($model->id);
        array_merge($list, array($model->id => $model->title, $childList);
    }
    return $list;
}
```

It's recursive, when you call it without params - you start with `parent_id=0` and get all the tree.

If you need indentation, use additional param in this func to set it (and increase it at every level)

Comment: I am using it like this `<?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'region', Region::model()->getList()); ?>` and it's returing an empty dropdownlist, am I making a mistake here?

Comment: @MahsaTeimourikia, Use `Region::getList()`. getList is static function of Region class.

Comment: 1. Can't find `dropDownListRow` func at Yii API, may be just dropDownList?

2. Try to debug my func - add `var_dump(Region::getList());` at view...or `var_dump($models,..)` inside function.

Comment: Ahhh, That's because I am using Yii Bootstrap, I tried also with CHtml::dropDownList, no results, I'll try to debug to see where is the problem then I will share the results

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static function getList($parent_id=null,$dash='',$list=array()) {
        $parents = ObjectCategory::find()->where(['parent_id' => $parent_id])->all();
        foreach($parents as $id => $p) {
             $list[$p->id] = $dash.$p->name;
             $list = ObjectCategory::getList($p->id,"-".$dash,$list);
        }
        return $list;
    }
// call on view 
echo  $form->field($model, 'parent_id')->dropDownList(backend\models\ObjectCategory::getList(null,''),['prompt' => 'Parent Category']);
```